# use of multiple google api in android app using switch

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop an app for android which is a personal mobile search engine based on the user's history and their current location. To search for results I have used the Google search api.

Unfortunately it has a limitation of 100 searches per day. To overcome this I had planned on using multiple Google search api keys (using switch). The problem I'm facing is that whenever the resultactivity (the function in which search and results are gathered) is called the counter is reset. As a result my app is using only 1 of the keys rather than all 3. Is there any way I can rectify this problem?

I have attached the code here (but without the switch).
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6z6YZ5pqVLdRjhGNmRpTHQ1Rzg/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me its my final year engineering project.

Comment: So maybe you can generate a random number then choose a key based on that number?

Comment: If you were to post a cut down version of the code with the lines relevant to the choice of key only in the question it might help!

Comment: the posible problem with random no is that suppose in case only one api is being called most of the time and others are left unused or less used, i might not be able to generate the result even though the other api are yet to reach its limitation

Comment: @NeilTownsend i haven't coded the switch statement yet i have the key but when i thought of using it this issue came in my mind.

Comment: @abhinav The general principle of StackOverflow is to post actual problems. Code your proposed solution and see what happens - it may work, or may not, depending on how you manage the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location where you store the number of searches to the `Application` class.
and if you the user quits the application you could store it in the `SharedPreferences` as well.

But I think the problem you are going to face is bigger then this. I don't really sure that Google allow to produce several keys for the same `SHA1 keystore` and the same package name including your application name.

Comment: can you suggest anyway in which i can get more no of results.. i have used different email id's to get the api

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with Google Search API. My experience come from their map API, and for what I know what you want to do is not possible there.